# jQuery collapsible panel (my own) problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to create a jQuery collapsible panel and, while there are plugins around for it I haven't found one that does exactly what I want so, am trying to roll my own using various examples I've found. While it works for the most part there's one bit that doesn't and I can't work out why.

(An example page is at http://www.thekmz.co.uk/misc/cpanel/index1.html)

How it works (or doesn't as the case maybe)

HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="collapsiblePanel" title="Example Collapsible Panel">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit... etc</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.extend({
        collapsiblePanel: function() {
        return $(this).each(initCollapsiblePanel);
    }
  });
})(jQuery);

function initCollapsiblePanel() {
    if ($(this).children().length == 0) {
        $(this).wrapInner("<div></div>");
    }    
    $(this).children().wrapAll("<div class='cpanelContent'></div>");
    $("<div class='cpanelTitle'><div>" + $(this).attr("title") + "</div><div class='cpanelToggle'>more</div></div>").prependTo($(this));
    $(".cpanelContent", this).hide();
    $(".cpanelTitle", this).click(toggleCollapsiblePanel);
}

function toggleCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(".cpanelContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle();

    if ($(".cpanelContent", $(this).parent()).is(":hidden")) {
        $(".cpanelToggle", this).html('more');
    } else {
        $(".cpanelToggle", this).html('close');
    }
}
```

CSS

```
#container {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
}

.collapsiblePanel {
    width:100%;
}

.cpanelTitle {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}

.cpanelToggle {
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    right:0px;
    font-style:italic;
}
```

So it takes a div with the class collapsiblePanel and creates various nested divs. The header div holds the Title and some toggle text floated to the right that will be 'more' or 'close' depending on whether the content panel is expaned or collapsed.

The bit that doesn't work is the

```
if ($(".cpanelContent", $(this).parent()).is(":hidden")) {
```

in the toggleCollapsiblePanel() function. The div toggles ok so It seems I'm selecting the content div alright but using the same to find out whether it is hidden or not (so I can change the text of the cPanelToggleDiv) always comes back as false - which indicates to me that I'm just not doing it correctly.

I put a load of console calls in there (in the example page linked above) to try and see what's going on but just can't see it.

Any help pointing out my hopelessness/confusion would be greatly appreciated.

Regards
Nymor

Comment: You could use an existing one, which fits your needs best, and modify that. Perhaps that could be easier.

Comment: Using Chrome, it seems to be working for me. On initial page load the console says `isHidden: true`, then, after opening it, it says `isHidden: false`.

Comment: @Wulf - In a way that's I'm trying - I've combined 2 different ones I found but the resultant div layout is different so I have to use a different selector

Comment: @Joseph - It would seem that way but the isHidden: true is from within the initialisation function. All the isHidden: false stuff is within the toggleCollapsiblePanel() function and it says false regardsless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check the `hidden` state in the `slideToggle` callback method. Unless the slide animation completes you cannot say whether its hidden or not. Try this

Here I did few other optimization as well, like using `this` which will point to the element it is sliding.

```
function toggleCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(".cpanelContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
           $(this).html('more');
       } else {
           $(this).html('close');
       }
   });
}
```

Comment: Ahh ... thanks Shankar. I've changed it now so it's in the callback and it works ok. I still have to use $(".cpanelToggle", $(this).parent()).html('more'); rather than $(this).html('more');
though as that text is within a div in the header rather than the element that's sliding - but nice job - thx

Comment: ps ... sorry can't upvote as I'm a complete noob and I don't have a reputation yet

Comment: Np @Nymor, glad it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the

```
    var open = false;
```

to your initCollapsiblePanel function.

Then updating the toggleCollapsiblePanel function replace:

```
    if ($(".cpanelContent", $(this).parent()).is(":hidden")) {...
```

with the following:

```
if (!open) {
    $(".cpanelToggle", this).html('more');
    open  = true;
} else {
    $(".cpanelToggle", this).html('close');
    open = false;

}
```

This should now change the more and close text.( i think this is what your after).
Si

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your test is running before the slideToggle has finished running. That means it will either have just become visible, or be fading out, in either case it will not be hidden.

You should move your text toggling into the slideToggle callback function, e.g.:

```
function toggleCollapsiblePanel() {
    $(".cpanelContent", $(this).parent()).slideToggle(600, function() {
        if ($(this).is(":hidden")) {
            $(this).html('more');
        } else {
            $(this).html('close');
        }   
    });    
}
```

Comment: thx Timbo - all down to using the callback as Shankar also stated - thx again.

Answer (score 0):

### [WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/roXon/3tsfT/2/)

The code:

```
function toggleCollapsiblePanel() {
    var cCp = $(".cpanelContent", $(this).parent());
    var cT  = $(".cpanelToggle" , this);

    check = cCp.is(":hidden") ? cT.html('close') : cT.html('more') ;
    cCp.slideToggle();
}
```

Comment: thx roXon - another alternative - just have to think whther I want the more/close label to change after the slide (callback) or before (your method). Nice to have choices either way - cheers.

Comment: P.S. I improved my code. Is more readable now. You can do also: `cCp.is(":visible") ? cT.html('more') : cT.html('close') ;`